# Can we call a function inside printf()?

Tags: c

```
printf("%d",func(i));
```

Is this possible in C?

Let us think that `func(i)` is separate function, can we call it inside `printf` or `scanf`?

Comment: Yes, of course, why not?

Comment: sure. did you tried it?

Comment: `func` returns `int`, *right* ? If so, sure you can. If not, stop lying to `printf` by telling it you're feeding it an `int` when you're not. Your last word in your post, `scanf`, is more complicated. There, it only make sense if the function returns an *address*, and since you've provided no example to ponder, it probably doesn't belong in this question.

Comment: Formally you dont call it "inside" printf. It is called befofre printf is called, as part of the parameter evaluation.

Comment: See the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28190271/2105501. It answers your exact question!

Comment: Make sure to use the correct return type. For instance, ```printf("%d", pow(2,3))``` won't work; it should be ```printf("%d", (int)pow(2,3))``` or ```printf("%f", pow(2,3))```.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  Although it's rather special in some ways, `printf` is just another function.  And a function call can be part of an expression.  And the arguments you pass to functions are themselves expressions.

An expression is anything you can compute.  So

```
i + 1
```

is an expression.  But just plain

```
i
```

is also a (simpler) expression.  And just plain

```
1
```

is an even simpler expression.

We build big expressions up out of littler ones.  So if `expr1` is an expression and `expr2` is another expression, then

```
expr1 + expr2
```

is a bigger expression that combines them.

Just as you can take two little expressions (sometimes we call these "subexpressions") and combine them to form a larger expression using the `+` operator, we can also take some expressions and combine them together by calling a function:

```
f(expr1, expr2)
```

Now, returning to your question, the call

```
func(i)
```

is an expression.  But when you call `printf`, what it expects to see for arguments is

```
printf(expression, expression, expression, ...)
```

Now, in `printf's` case, that first expression must be a string, and it's virtually always a constant string.  But the remaining arguments can be anything: `1`, `i`, `i + 1`, `func(1)`, or just about anything:

```
printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", 1, i, i+1, func(i), i+1+func(i));
```

The only thing to worry about, of course, is that you have as many expressions as additional arguments as you have `%` signs in the first argument (that is, in the format string), and the types of those additional arguments must match the types expected by the particular format specifiers you have used (`%d`, `%f`, `%s`, etc.).

Comment: You might add that `func(i)` in `printf("%d",func(i));` must promote to `int` as `printf` expects this type for the argument corresponding to `%d`. `func` must be a function returning a type that promotes to `int`, such as `_Bool`, `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short` and `int` itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int ,int );

void main()
{
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    printf("Sum of %d and %d is: %d",num1,num2,sum(num1,num2));  //function call in print statement
    }

    int sum(int num1,int num2)     //function to add two numbers``
    {
            int result;
            result=num1+num2;
            return result;
            }
```